# How do I add background color to grand children sibebar menus?

Tags: css, wordpress

I am using advanced sidebar menus page. Link is below:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-sidebar-menu/

The plugin provides widgets which allows users add background as well as text colors to child menus.

However, it doesn't provide the option to add background colors for grand children menus.

In the sample code below, we are able to add background color to child menu called Purchasing.

However, we are having problem figuring out how to add background colors to grand child Online Content and Hot Items.

Does anyone know how this can be handled?

We don't want to play with the original code because an update to the plugin will wipe all of that out.

The sample code below shows the classes being used for the sidebar menus.

```
<div id="advanced_sidebar_menu-8-wrap" data-js="advanced_sidebar_menu-8-wrap">
   <ul class="child-sidebar-menu">
      <li class="page_item page-item-2867 page_item_has_children current_page_item has_children"><a href="http://departments/?page_id=2867">Purchasing</a>
        <ul class="children">
      <li class="page_item page-item-5125 page_item_has_children has_children"><a href="http://departments/?page_id=5125">Online Content</a>
        <ul class="children">
        <li class="page_item page-item-2895"><a href="http://departments/?page_id=2895">division Descriptions</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-2911"><a href="http://departments/?page_id=2911">Oracle</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-2917"><a href="http://departments/?page_id=2917">Contracts</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-5110"><a href="http://departments/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/2018.pdf" target="_blank">Certified</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-2927"><a href="http://departments/?page_id=2927">Policies / Procedures</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-2960"><a href="http://departments/?page_id=2960">Forms</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-2936"><a href="http://departments/?page_id=2936">Special Notices</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-2943"><a href="http://departments/?page_id=2943">FAQ</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-5118"><a href="http://departments/?page_id=5118">Online Client Items</a></li>
         </ul>
       </li>
       <li class="page_item page-item-5123 page_item_has_children has_children"><a href="#">Hot Items</a>
         <ul class="children">
        <li class="page_item page-item-3460"><a href="http://departments/purchasing/pdf/PurchasingRestricted.pdf" target="_blank">Purchasing Restricted Item Policy</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-5120"><a href="http://departments/purchasing/oracle_pdf/UpgradeAwareness.pdf" target="_blank">DeKalb 11.5.10.2 Upgrade Awareness Documentation</a></li>
         </ul>
           </li>
         </ul>
        </li>
       </ul><!-- End .child-sidebar-menu -->
     </div>
```

This is what we have tried so far:

```
#advanced_sidebar_menu-8-wrap .child-sidebar-menu .page_item page-item-2867 .page_item_has_children .current_page_item has_children .children .page_item .page-item-5125 .page_item_has_children .has_children li a {
    background-color: #009B32 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will suffice.

```css
#advanced_sidebar_menu-8-wrap .page_item.has_children .page_item.has_children > a {
  background-color: #035;
}
```

```html
<div id="advanced_sidebar_menu-8-wrap" data-js="advanced_sidebar_menu-8-wrap">
  <ul class="child-sidebar-menu">
    <li class="page_item page-item-2867 page_item_has_children current_page_item has_children"><a href="http://departments/?page_id=2867">Purchasing</a>
      <ul class="children">
        <li class="page_item page-item-5125 page_item_has_children has_children"><a href="http://departments/?page_id=5125">Online Content</a>
          <ul class="children">
            <li class="page_item page-item-2895"><a href="http://departments/?page_id=2895">division Descriptions</a></li>
            <li class="page_item page-item-2911"><a href="http://departments/?page_id=2911">Oracle</a></li>
            <li class="page_item page-item-2917"><a href="http://departments/?page_id=2917">Contracts</a></li>
            <li class="page_item page-item-5110"><a href="http://departments/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/2018.pdf" target="_blank">Certified</a></li>
            <li class="page_item page-item-2927"><a href="http://departments/?page_id=2927">Policies / Procedures</a></li>
            <li class="page_item page-item-2960"><a href="http://departments/?page_id=2960">Forms</a></li>
            <li class="page_item page-item-2936"><a href="http://departments/?page_id=2936">Special Notices</a></li>
            <li class="page_item page-item-2943"><a href="http://departments/?page_id=2943">FAQ</a></li>
            <li class="page_item page-item-5118"><a href="http://departments/?page_id=5118">Online Client Items</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-5123 page_item_has_children has_children"><a href="#">Hot Items</a>
          <ul class="children">
            <li class="page_item page-item-3460"><a href="http://departments/purchasing/pdf/PurchasingRestricted.pdf" target="_blank">Purchasing Restricted Item Policy</a></li>
            <li class="page_item page-item-5120"><a href="http://departments/purchasing/oracle_pdf/UpgradeAwareness.pdf" target="_blank">DeKalb 11.5.10.2 Upgrade Awareness Documentation</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <!-- End .child-sidebar-menu -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and prompt response.

Your code has background color on all the other menus except the two that I actually needed help on.

We are trying to have background color for only Online Content and Hot Items.

Comment: You're welcome. Perhaps my edit will do it. Basically you target all links in the desired level and issue the background color to those.

Comment: you are simply the best!!!!

That did it. I truly appreciate your help.

Comment: Haha no problem dude :) glad that I could help you.